# Track HTTP(S) Network calls being made by an Android Device

Tags: android, man-in-the-middle, account-security, wireshark, burp-suite

I am planning to track the Network calls being made by apps and the website of an Android Device.

I have used the Burp Suite tool for tracking the network calls.
Until now the Android Device and the Laptop were connected to the same WIFI.

But now I am planning to use an emulator which will not be hosted in my Laptop.

Is there any way to track network calls of an Android Device which is not connected to the same WIFI as my laptop?

Comment: Is your Android device rooted or have bootloader unlocked?

Comment: @defalt Thanks for the comment. My Device is rooted. I have rooted it using the Kingo Root app.

Comment: I use [tcpdump for android](https://www.androidtcpdump.com/).

Comment: @defalt Thanks for the answer. Your answer seems to look really interesting. Can you please post an answer so that I can accept it. Also, it would be really grateful if you can provide the link to any tutorial which describes the steps to set up and use tcpdump., Thanks once again.

Comment: Burpsuite is better than tcpdump. tcpdump cannot decrypt https traffic. tcpdump is useful when you want to capture every network traffic and not just http.

Comment: @defalt Yes, you are absolutely right that Burpsuit is better than tcpdump. But can a burp suit be configured to be used with an Android device that is not using the same wifi as my laptop?

Comment: You can ask in [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) if burpsuit fits your requirement.

Comment: @defalt Thanks. I will definitely do so. Meanwhile can you please post an answer to this so that I can accept it.

Comment: My answer is not valid for the condition you are asking for. Leave this question as it is. Someone with a better suggestion may answer it with all in one tool.

Comment: @defalt Not an issue. Let's wait and see if someone has a better solution. Thanks for your time.